# Is it possible to connect to an Access db via ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, ms-access

I created an OLE DB Connection in ArcCatalog Database Connections. If I right click on one of my db tables I can "Create a Feature Class > From XY Table" and continue with my data processing.

However, if I try to incorporate this step into a geoprocessing model (ModelBuilder) I can't seem to access the tables through my .odc connection. See image.

Is there another way to those Access tables within ModelBuilder, or am I doing this wrong way?

MS Access version is 2010.ArcGIS version is 10.1. I connected to .accdb.

[image]

Comment: What version is the db, .mdb or .accdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the model that will connect to an Access 2010 database table and create a point layer from the data.

[image: Model]

You need to create a Table View and feed that into the Make XY Event Layer tool. This is an in memory layer which can be used in processing but if you want to create a permanent version you need to save it, copy features will do this.

When you set the input table you need to navigate into your OLE DB connection by double clicking it to see the tables in the database then choose the appropriate table.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but not completely for some reason: I have two different tables (say A,B) within the same Access db, both of which have XY location values. For some reason, the model works when it is drawing the values from table A but not when drawing values from table B. The error msg is: Error 999999: The coordinates or measures are out of bounds. But B's values are within the ranges of A's values (for both X and Y locations). Any ideas?

Comment: I would first double check that the XY fields are numeric and don't contain null values. Are you setting the coordinate system to an appropriate value in the make XY event tool? I would then add the table to ArcMap and just use the Make XY event layer tool to make sure it's working there.